# validateOrThrow implementation

Tags: java, functional-programming

I want to achieve something like this in a functional way. Any help?

```
public static Function<String[],Void> validateLength3 = (String[] input) -> {
   if(input.length != 3) 
       throw new Exception("length not equals 3");
}
```

I expect it to return nothing if array `length == 3`.

`Else` throw an `Exception`.

Comment: `Function` is not allowed to throw any checked exceptions, define a custom interface for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `Function`'s `apply()` method  requires a return value.
2. `Function`'s `apply()` method cannot throw a checked exception.

You can use a `Consumer<String>` which throws a `RuntimeException` instead:

```
public static Consumer<String[]> validateLength3 =
    (String[] input) -> { if(input.length != 3) throw new RuntimeException("length not equals 3");};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a separate function for validation. There are helper classes in popular libraries which already do what you need.

I.e [Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) in Google Guava

you can write something like

```
Preconditions.checkState(input.length == 3, "length not equals 3");
```